Create a Vault UI user using the vault CLI
I would like to create a hashicorp vault UI login user before ever having to login to the GUI with the root token.
Initially I have the root token and CLI access to the vault.
How can I create a GUI login username+password and grant complete read rights via the CLI exclusively?
The vault is newly installed, essentially unconfigured with any policies.
This is intended to be part of a BASH script.


Authenticate with the root token.

vault login <root token>

Enable the userpass authentication method.

vault auth enable userpass

Create a Vault policy for global read permissions.

# read-only.hcl
path "*" {
  capabilities = ["read", "list"]
}

vault policy write read-only read-only.hcl


Create an user with the read permissions policy attached.

vault write auth/userpass/users/<username> password=<password> policies=read-only

Login to the GUI with the userpass method with the created user.


Just a recommendation; You should not use the root token, just use it for the initial configuration and then remove it.
You can read for further details in the official documentation

@ericcco The question describes an initial setup scenario where the only authentication available is the root token.

Agree, it was just a complementary note for the future! Thank you Matthew!

thanks all. great answers
